# NoneType object has no attribute 'find'

Tags: google-drive

I've been getting this error a lot in Google Drive:

[image]

If I quit and restart the program, it pops back up right away. I've tried reinstalling but that didn't help. What does this do and what can I do to fix it?

I tried moving the directory Google Drive uses and it still has this issue.

Comment: have you tried disconnecting and reconnecting your account as it suggests?

Comment: @FrankThomas Yes

Comment: Weird, that looks like a Python error. I don't know of any other languages that use anything called `NoneType` & refer to members as attributes -- though I haven't coded in all that many languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this thread has been dead for almost a year, but I didn't find the right answer anywhere, so I thought I'd reply for posterity. I had the same problem on my mac, so I went into the log file and figured out what the problem was and fixed it.

1. In my case, the logfile was located at ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Drive/user_default/sync_log.log). Open in the text editor of your choice.
2. Search this string: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'file_name'`
3. There are a few instances of that string for each error, it seems. Look at the previous line. For one instance, there will be a filename, in my case it was `name=u'outline_template.pages'` (a document I created in the Pages app)
4. Go into your drive folder and delete / move that file (in my case, I just pulled out all the Pages documents in there)
5. Restart Drive. If the problem persists, repeat steps 2-5 until Drive works again. In my case, killing the Pages files off did it.
6. Have a beer to celebrate.

Answer (score 1):

I also found myself hit the same "sorry good drive needs to quit" problem with same nonetype and no attribute 'find'. After looking for solution for a little while I tried the following and it seems to be working with me. 
 So, basically, what i did was to ask the drive to get a fresh copy of the current google drive on my local drive. Following was what i had done step by step...

1. quit google drive
2. change the original folder 'Google Drive' to 'old Google Drive'
3. restart google drive
4. google drive complaints that the folder does not exist, so the syncing quit.
5. I then created a folder 'Google Drive'
6. restart the google drive
7. after a little while, my sync is completed and the drive did not crash at all.

Hope this may help...

Comment: Update your post if the syncing is successfully completed and remove the "finger-cross" section please

Comment: Yes, it did and my drive is now happy living locally. thanks for your suggestion.